# Modification in ID3 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

Is there any way that we could modify the ID3 decision tree construction algorithm to build a decision tree while allowing up to one error.

e.g After if there is a game like http://en.akinator.com that asks questions and based on the answers output some class variable. Can we accommodate up to one error in our ID3 algorithm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ID3` algorithm is not very sensitive to errors if you have sufficient number of examples, because it picks the most common label for a subset. Its "stop conditions" for turning a subtree into a leaf are:

1. every element belongs to the same class -- you can experiment with weakening it to get better generalization;
2. there are no more attributes to be selected, the leaf is labelled with the most common class of the examples in the subset;
3. there are no examples in the subset, the leaf is labelled with the most common class of the examples in the parent node subset.